GCC ignores already stored constant in FPU register on -O2
I got simple function that calculates sin cos :
https://godbolt.org/z/v61GP9qvj
Compiler flags set for cortex m4 MCU with FPU
question is why in disassembly at line 34:
vldr.32 s13, .L35+20
it loads 0.225 const and then discards it, but at line 58:
vldr.32 s14, .L35+20
loads it again! making local variable does not change that behavior. Only changing to -Os keeps this variable alive in whole function.
MCU have 32 FPU registers, there is a plenty area to store that var.. why it does not keep it with O2 ?
Changed compiler flags, tried manual optimization, no effect.
Code:
#define sinB    1.2732395f
#define C       0.40528473f
#define P       0.225f
//between -pi/2 pi/2  range
#define cosA    1.0f
//over pi/2 range
#define cos2A   3.0f
#define cos2B   2.546479f
//1st calculate sine-like parabola with 3 main points A B C
//2nd calculate difference between normal and squared parabola (because normal is too big and squared is smaller) to get good approximation
//use P as coefficiend of squared parabola (0.225 is best)
#define M_TWOPI 6.283185307179586476925286766559f
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433f
#define M_PI_2 3.1415926535897932384626433f/2.0f
void porabolicSinCos(float angle, float *sin, float *cos) { 
    //always wrap input angle to -PI..PI
    while (angle < -M_PI) {
        angle += M_TWOPI;
    }

    while (angle > M_PI) {
        angle -= M_TWOPI;
    }

    float anglePow2 = angle * angle;
    //compute sine
    if (angle < 0.0f) {
        *sin = sinB * angle + C * anglePow2;
    } else {
        *sin = sinB * angle - C * anglePow2;
    }
    // Q * y + P * y * abs(y)
    if (*sin < 0.0f) {
        *sin = P * (*sin * -*sin - *sin) + *sin;
    } else {
        *sin = P * (*sin * *sin - *sin) + *sin;
    }

    //compute in 3 ranges to avoid angle shifts and keep angle^2 optimization
    //A=1, B=0, C=-4/pi^2
    if (angle < -M_PI_2) {
        *cos = cos2A + cos2B * angle + C * anglePow2;
    } else if (angle > M_PI_2) {
        *cos = cos2A - cos2B * angle + C * anglePow2;
    } else {
        *cos = cosA - C * anglePow2;
    }

    if (*cos < 0.0f) {
        *cos = P * (*cos * -*cos - *cos) + *cos;
    } else {
        *cos = P * (*cos * *cos - *cos) + *cos;
    }
}

ASM:
porabolicSinCos:
        vldr.32 s15, .L35
        vcmpe.f32       s0, s15
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        bpl     .L2
        vldr.32 s14, .L35+4
.L4:
        vadd.f32        s0, s0, s14
        vcmpe.f32       s0, s15
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        bmi     .L4
.L2:
        vldr.32 s15, .L35+8
        vcmpe.f32       s0, s15
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        ble     .L5
        vldr.32 s14, .L35+4
.L7:
        vsub.f32        s0, s0, s14
        vcmpe.f32       s0, s15
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        bgt     .L7
.L5:
        vmul.f32        s15, s0, s0
        vldr.32 s14, .L35+12
        vldr.32 s13, .L35+16
        vmul.f32        s14, s15, s14
        vcmpe.f32       s0, #0
        vmov.f32        s15, s14
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        ite     mi
        vfmami.f32      s15, s0, s13
        vfnmspl.f32     s15, s0, s13
        vldr.32 s13, .L35+20
        vcmpe.f32       s15, #0
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        vmov.f32        s12, s15
        ite     mi
        vfnmami.f32     s12, s15, s15
        vfnmspl.f32     s12, s15, s15
        vfma.f32        s15, s12, s13
        vldr.32 s13, .L35+24
        vstr.32 s15, [r0]
        vcmpe.f32       s0, s13
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        bpl     .L31
        vldr.32 s13, .L35+28
        vmov.f32        s15, #3.0e+0
        vfma.f32        s15, s0, s13
        vadd.f32        s15, s15, s14
.L16:
        vcmpe.f32       s15, #0
        vmov.f32        s13, s15
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        ite     mi
        vfnmami.f32     s13, s15, s15
        vfnmspl.f32     s13, s15, s15
        vldr.32 s14, .L35+20
        vfma.f32        s15, s13, s14
        vstr.32 s15, [r1]
        bx      lr
.L31:
        vldr.32 s15, .L35+32
        vcmpe.f32       s0, s15
        vmrs    APSR_nzcv, FPSCR
        ble     .L32
        vldr.32 s13, .L35+28
        vmov.f32        s15, #3.0e+0
        vfms.f32        s15, s0, s13
        vadd.f32        s15, s15, s14
        b       .L16
.L32:
        vmov.f32        s15, #1.0e+0
        vsub.f32        s15, s15, s14
        b       .L16
.L35:
        .word   -1068953637
        .word   1086918619
        .word   1078530011
        .word   1053786491
        .word   1067645315
        .word   1046898278
        .word   -1077342245
        .word   1076033923
        .word   1070141403


Please [edit] your question and add the code to your question.  Stack Overflow questions must be self-contained and be understandable even if outside lilnks go down.

Actually it uses the value in s13 on the line "vfma.f32 s15,s12,s13" just prior to reloading. A more reasonable question is why doesn't it put the new constant in s12 (which is not used again past that point). Compilers seem to have favourite registers for some operations...

Yes, with some manual optimizations you can make it firstly store in s12, and s12 not used anywhere later. but then compiler just ignores s12 and loads value in s13 again facepalm.
nb: manual means they have no effect, because compiler does pretty good optimization by itself
